# I am unable to get the result for the given code

Tags: python, json, data-analysis, geopandas, folium

I am unable to get the data read from shape file and convert in "Geojson".

## The code to read the shape file and it has been executed

```
'pl= "C:/Users/jshridha/Desktop/Python Database/Vaestoruudukko_2017.shp"
'pop= gpd.read_file(pl)'
'pop.head()'
```

## The code to convert into json is showing error.

```
'pop_gjson= folium.features.GeoJson(pop)'
```

## It is not executed and shown error

```
'pop_gjson= folium.features.GeoJson(pop)'
```

error
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYIBH.png)

The code has to be executed but shown errors to pass an arguments.

Link for Data
"https://www.hsy.fi/sites/AvoinData/AvoinData/SYT/Tietoyhteistyoyksikko/Shape%20(Esri)/V%C3%A4est%C3%B6tietoruudukko/Vaestotietoruudukko_2017_SHP.zip"

Output of # pop.crs code

'{'proj': 'tmerc',
 'lat_0': 0,
 'lon_0': 25,
 'k': 1,
 'x_0': 25500000,
 'y_0': 0,
 'ellps': 'GRS80',
 'units': 'm',
 'no_defs': True}'

Comment: can you share the file with us?

Comment: What is the output of `pop.crs` ? It looks like your shape file may not have crs associated with it. Either you need to fix the raw shapefile so it does, or assign the correct crs to `pop` using `pop = pop.to_crs(your_new_crs)`

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Link for the file has been attached.

Comment: @macaw_9227 Output for the command has been attached so have a look.

Comment: How did you install `geopandas`? There were issues with `pyproj` before, but it should be okay if you install `geopandas` and all dependencies from conda-forge.

Comment: Package has been working correctly..